# Spring @RequestMapping and ControllerLinkBuilder

Tags: spring, spring-hateoas

All my controllers classes are annotated with

```
@RequestMapping("${base-path}")
```

I'm using Spring hateoas, so I had to create a `ResourceProcessor`. Inside it I have

```
@Value("${base-path}")
private String apiBasePath;

...

resource.add(linkTo(methodOn(MyController.class, apiBasePath)
```

The issue is that ${base-path} is considered by ControllerLinkBuilder a variable to be replaced as a path variable, so the result is

```
http://localhost:8080/$/api/[myControllerPath]
```

Instead it should have been replaced with the environment variable.
How should I do?